# Splitting XPATH produces more results than the actual possible

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to gather some historical data of managers of football clubs and noticed a weird behaviour. I am trying to scrape the history table of the clubs managed by a manager from this website : https://www.transfermarkt.co.in/carlo-ancelotti/profil/trainer/523

With the entire xpath as a single input to fetch the response, the code works alright as expected

```
clubs = response.xpath("//div[@id='yw1']//td[@class='hauptlink no-border-links']//a/text()").extract()
print(clubs)

Output : ['Everton', 'SSC Napoli', 'Bayern Munich ', 'Real Madrid', 'Paris SG',\
'Chelsea', 'Milan', 'Juventus', 'AC Parma', 'Reggiana', 'Italy']
```

That's the list of clubs from the foretold history table. However, while the xpath is split as shown in the following code, it fetches names of clubs from the other table too in spite of it having a totally different div id. I mean it's not 'yw1' for the other table

```
career_table = response.xpath("//div[@id='yw1']")
clubs = career_table.xpath("//td[@class='hauptlink no-border-links']//a/text()").extract()
print(clubs)

Output : ['Everton', 'SSC Napoli', 'Bayern Munich ', 'Real Madrid', 'Paris SG',\
'Chelsea', 'Milan', 'Juventus', 'AC Parma', 'Reggiana', 'Italy', 'Milan', 'Retired',\
'AS Roma', 'Milan', 'AC Parma', 'AS Roma', 'Parma U19', 'AC Parma', 'Reggiolo', 'Parma U19']
```

Can someone enlighten me, what is that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **relative** XPath (starting `.`):

```
clubs = career_table.xpath(".//td[@class='hauptlink no-border-links']//a/text()").extract()
print(clubs)
```

Comment: Damn! That 'period' almost cost me 3 hours as I tried every possible variant of achieving the task. I never noticed that anywhere, perhaps, the side effects of code-first learning approach! Thank you so much btw